# Retain original format of datetime64 when converting to list

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(DT.datetime(2016,8,1), DT.datetime(2016,8,9)), columns=['a','b'] )
>>>df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2016-08-01', '2016-08-02', '2016-08-03', '2016-08-04',
           '2016-08-05', '2016-08-06', '2016-08-07', '2016-08-08',
           '2016-08-09'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D', tz=None)
>>>df.index.values.tolist()

[1470009600000000000L,
 1470096000000000000L,
 1470182400000000000L,
 1470268800000000000L,
 1470355200000000000L,
 1470441600000000000L,
 1470528000000000000L,
 1470614400000000000L,
 1470700800000000000L]
```

Basically the datetime64[ns] format is automatically converted to long format. Is there a way that I can keep the format for those operations otherwise I need to convert it back if I wanted to access the df content. For example

```
>>>df.loc[df.index.values.tolist()[3]]
```

does not work, while

```
>>>df.loc[df.index.values[3]]
```

works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain the original format while converting them to list by using [`.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.date) of `pandas.DatetimeIndex.date` which returns the date part of the Timestamps.

```
In [14]: df.index.date.tolist()
Out[14]: 
[datetime.date(2016, 8, 1),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 2),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 3),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 4),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 5),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 6),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 7),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 8),
 datetime.date(2016, 8, 9)]
```